# SSIS Job parameter value radio button "Use default value from package" not selected

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, ssis-2019

I have an SSIS job which has a bool parameter set to True and should get the value from the package by having the "Use default value from package" selected. But when I deploy the package the "Edit Value" is selected.

[image: SSISDB -DeployProject]

I don't have much experience with SSIS Jobs, from what I have read this radio button is selected by default but is being overridden somewhere (I could be totally wrong)

Any pointers appreciated - I need the **"Use default value from package"** to be selected by default and know it's a config issue but no idea where this value is being set.

I am able to manually change it but need this to be configured correctly before we deploy to production server.

Any pointers appreciated

[image: Configure job properties]

Comment: you need to check the configuration settings at the job level